# Hibernate UserType problem

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying my hands on Hibernate's userType and struck in some problem.here is my mapping file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="MyClass"
      table="MYTABLE">
      <id name="uuid" type="java.lang.String">
         <column name="UUID" />
         <generator class="uuid" />
      </id>

      <property name="myClass_UserType" type="MyClassUserType" >
         <column name="A"/>
         <column name="B"/>
         <column name="C"/>
        </property>

   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and here is the code from my CompositeUserType

```
@Override
   public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement ps, Object arg1, int index,
         SessionImplementor arg3) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

      if(arg1==null){
         //todo
      }
      else{
          MyClass_UserType mc=(MyClass_UserType)arg1;
          mc=dao.save(mc);
          ps.setString(index, mc.getXYZ());
          ps.setString(index+1, mc.getXYZ());
          ps.setString(index+2, mc.getXYZ());
           ps.setString(index+3, mc.getXYZ());

      }
   }
```

i want to get access to MyClass instance inside the nullSafeSet(...) method.
i have access to MyClass_UserType in this method but some how not able to get instance of the MyClass.

Is there any way to get reference/access of this MyClass instance

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the difference between "MyClassuserType" (from the mapping), "MyClass_UserType" (from the code) and "my CompositeUserType" (from the text)?

Comment: @ Stefan Steinegger:i guess i have written three words for same thing well MyClass_UserType/MyClassUserType and the third one are CompositeUserType which i have created to handle the case

Answer (score 1):

Is u define the MyClass in your working package, as mapping file says that u are mapped a tabel **MYTABLE** with **MyClass** but really define it, if it is then i am sure that the instance of MyClass is access in inside any class within the same package or somewhere else through import so plz chek it your MyClass.

Comment: This is quite a long sentence.

Comment: And could use a dictionary too